# RoundedImageView has disturbing corners

Tags: android, transparency

I want to remove those semi-transparent corners from my [RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView). How do I do that?

[image]

this is my xml:

```
 <com.makeramen.RoundedImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/avatar_image"
            android:src="@drawable/nature1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            app:riv_corner_radius="30dip"
            app:riv_border_width="2dip"
            app:riv_border_color="#333333"
            app:riv_mutate_background="true"
            app:riv_tile_mode="repeat"
            app:riv_oval="false" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to the xml did it.

```
android:background="#00000000"
```